# TimeScaleData on C#

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I am migrating a macro code into VSTO. I am having problems with TimeScaleData. the macro code is like this.

```
For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If tsk.Summary = False And tsk.Duration <> 0 Then
        With tsk 
            Set tsvs = .TimeScaleData(StartDate:=ActiveProject.ProjectStart, EndDate:=ActiveProject.ProjectFinish, Type:=pjTaskTimescaledBaselineWork, timescaleunit:=pjTimescaleWeeks, Count:=1)
        End With
        For Each tsv In tsvs 
           differencedate = 0
           If tsk.BaselineStart <> "NA" And tsk.BaselineFinish <> "NA" Then

                If tsk.BaselineStart >= tsv.StartDate And tsk.BaselineStart <= tsv.StartDate + 7 And tsk.BaselineFinish <= tsv.StartDate + 7 Then
                    differencedate = Application.DateDifference(tsk.BaselineStart, tsk.BaselineFinish, ActiveProject.Calendar) / 60

                ElseIf tsk.BaselineStart >= tsv.StartDate And tsk.BaselineStart <= tsv.StartDate + 7 And tsk.BaselineFinish >= tsv.StartDate + 7 Then
                     differencedate = (Application.DateDifference(tsk.BaselineStart, tsv.StartDate + 7, ActiveProject.Calendar)) / 60


                ElseIf tsk.BaselineStart <= tsv.StartDate And tsk.BaselineFinish >= tsv.StartDate And tsk.BaselineFinish <= tsv.StartDate + 7 Then
                     differencedate = (Application.DateDifference(tsv.StartDate, tsk.BaselineFinish, ActiveProject.Calendar)) / 60

                ElseIf tsk.BaselineStart <= tsv.StartDate And tsk.BaselineFinish >= tsv.StartDate + 7 Then
                     differencedate = Application.DateDifference(tsv.StartDate, tsv.StartDate + 7, ActiveProject.Calendar) / 60

                End If
          End If
    Next
    End if
Next
```

I need to translate this to C#, anyone who can help?

Comment: whats the problem exactly? any error message?

Comment: I can not use the TimeScaleData on C#

Comment: foreach (Task task in taskList)
{
                if (task.Summary == false && System.Convert.ToInt32(task.Duration) != 0)
                {
                    TimeScaleValues tsvs = task.TimeScaleData(project.ProjectStart, project.ProjectFinish, PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledBaselineWork, PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleWeeks, 1);
                    foreach (TimeScaleValue tsv in tsvs)
                    {
                        if (task.BaselineStart.ToString() != "NA" && task.BaselineFinish.ToString() != "NA")
                        {}}}}
having problem with getting tsvs

Comment: @GilbertAllanWong is that an answer or a Tweet? ;-)

Comment: both? actually the error os I am using Assignment instead of task.

Answer (score 0):

What code do you have so far? Any exceptions in the code?

Anyway, you can use automatic [code converters](http://converter.telerik.com) to get started quickly. Then you can correct the code manually.

Take a look at the sample code listed in the [Microsoft Project: TimeScaleData Method from .NET without GC.Collect](http://colbyafrica.blogspot.com/2010/12/microsoft-project-timescaledata-method.html) article.

Comment: //TimeScaleValue tsv;
            //TimeScaleValues tsvs;

            //foreach (Task task in taskList)
            //{
            //    tsvs = task.TimeScaleData(task.Start, task.Finish, PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledBaselineWork, PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleWeeks, 1);
            //}

I tried to do the same logic but I am having error on invalid arguments, 

it seems that TimeScaleData will work only on assignments.

Comment: the problem is I need an exact conversion of the above codes to C# VSTO